# Inverse Laplace transform of $1/(1+\sqrt{1+s^2})$

Tags: laplace-transform

A seemingly simple function,

$F(s)=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1+s^2}}$.

But what is its inverse Laplace transform?

If there is not a closed form, can I get some long/short time asymptotic?

It must have something to do with the Bessel J function.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the trick of writing
$$\frac 1 {1 + \sqrt {1 + s^2}} =
\frac 1 s \sqrt {1 + \frac 1 {s^2}} - \frac 1 {s^2},$$
which holds for $s$ in the right half-plane. Then
$$\mathcal L^{-1} \!{\left[ \frac 1 {1 + \sqrt {1 + s^2}} \right]} =
-\mathcal L^{-1}[s^{-2}] +
 \sum_{k \geq 0} \binom {1/2} k \mathcal L^{-1}[s^{-2 k - 1}] = \\
-t + \sum_{k \geq 0} \binom {1/2} k \frac {t^{2 k}} {\Gamma(2 k + 1)} =
{_1\hspace{-2px}F_2} {\left( -\frac 1 2; \frac 1 2, 1; -\frac {t^2} 4 \right)} - t.$$
The hypergeometric function can be converted to a combination of Bessel and Struve functions.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is brilliant!

Comment: May I ask a follow up though. So what happens if my function becomes $$\frac{1}{c+\sqrt{1+s^2}}$$, where $c$ is a constant other than 1. Then the "partial fraction" still works, the binomial theorem still works, but the product is not as nice and we don't just get 1/s that can be absorbed. In this case, is there a way other than convolution?

Comment: For $c \neq \pm 1$, the inverse transform will contain an integral of $e^{a t} J_1(t)/t$ (which is the convolution that you mentioned). Most likely some very general special functions will be required to express it in closed form.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Let the inverse Laplace be $f(t)$ . Then what is the Laplace of $\frac{f(t)}{t}$